# Change a form value, from a hook of Struts Action (Liferay 6.2)

Tags: java, liferay, hook, liferay-6, portlet

I´m just trying to change a value that is coming from a form. I have hooked a `Struts Action`, to change that value, and then continue with the default `processAction`. But it's not applying the changes.

This is my hook code:

```
public class EditRecordDisplayPortletAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {
    ...

    public void processAction(
            StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws Exception {
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

        ...
        //Stuff that is working here ...
        ...

        //Here I change the value that is comming from the form that should be used later:
        DynamicActionRequest dynamicActionRequest = null;
        Map<String, String[]> params = new HashMap();

        String observationInputKey = getObservationInputKey();
        params.put(observationInputKey, new String[]{"Here goes some text I have calculated in the hook."});
            dynamicActionRequest = new DynamicActionRequest(actionRequest, params, false);
        //Continues with the normal operation, but it's not using the new values:
        originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(
            originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, dynamicActionRequest,
            actionResponse);
    }
    ...
```

I'm using the `DynamicActionRequest`, since I can't change the `__actionRequest__` . Looking for more information, here someone explains something similar, that should be working:
[Wrap actionRequest with a DynamicActionRequest](https://community.liferay.com/es/forums/-/message_boards/message/26284872)

Answer (score 0):

Following the example of the forum post that you link, you can create the DynamicActionRequest a lot simpler. Please try that:

```
public void processAction(
        StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
        PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws Exception {
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

    ...
    //Stuff that is working here ...
    ...

    DynamicActionRequest dynamicActionRequest = new DynamicActionRequest(actionRequest);

    String observationInputKey = getObservationInputKey();
    dynamicActionRequest.setParameter(observationInputKey, "Here goes some text I have calculated in the hook.");

    //Continues with the normal operation, but it's not using the new values:
    originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(
        originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, dynamicActionRequest,
        actionResponse);
}
...
```

Admitted, the [javadoc for DynamicActionRequest](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/DynamicActionRequest.html) doesn't contain more than the method names, but you're specifying the boolean parameter `inherit` to the constructor as `false`. That might be your only problem.

Comment: As you say, the javadoc is not very explicit, I tried with the more complex `constructor` with inherit because the`new DynamicActionRequest(actionRequest)` didn't work neither.